# avoid (shortening) too many else if php

Tags: php

I have this code but in my opinion it's too many lines. I'm new into programming so that's why I have questions.
I think there should be a shorter way to make it work without this if else loop, switch or is it ok like it's now?

if `$total==21` then  `mysql_query("UPDATE user SET left = '20'`, `$total==20` then `left=19` and so on until the `$total=1` and `left=0`.

```
if ($total==21 )
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET `left` = '20' WHERE `user` = 'user1' ") or die(mysql_error() );
    }   


else if ($total==20)
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET `left` = '19' WHERE `user` = 'user1' ") or die(mysql_error() );
    }   

    ....

else if ($total==1)
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET `left` = '0' WHERE `user` = 'user1' ") or die(mysql_error() );
    }   


else {

echo nl2br("0 left");

}
```

Merry Christmas !

Comment: yes, there is a shorter way: You can include variables to an update. So `$total-1` would be the value you wanna write to db.

Comment: But please refrain from using `mysql_*` functions, as they are old, deprecated and removed in latest php.

Comment: There is no need for the `nl2br` function there, as the content don't include any `\n` inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using PDO or Mysqli instead of the deprecated old mysql driver. This should solve your issue for now:

```
$total = (int) $total;
if ($total <= 0) {
    echo '0 left';
} else {
    $total--;
    mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET `left` = '$total' WHERE `user` = 'user1' ") or die(mysql_error() );
}
```

Notice how I am hardcoding the variable to be an integer, this way it wouldn't be venerable to injections (in the event it comes from the client side).

Answer (score 1):

First, look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1), and then something like:

```
if($total > 0 && $total < 22) {
    $left = $total - 1;
    // prepare("UPDATE `user` SET `left` = ? WHERE `user` = 'user1'")
    // bind_param('i', $left)
    // execute()
}
```